# How to create a pipeline to build and release a Docker compose, with Azure Devops using the graphical interface (GUI)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-service

Well, how can I create a pipeline to build and release a Docker compose, with Azure Devops through the graphical interface (GUI) I am not an expert in devops but I have this challenge in my work.

Comment: Title should be in English, too

Comment: Hi @Carlos Petit Quintero, How are things going? Have you tried the suggestions in the answers? Is any one of them helpful to you? Please have a try. Any progress, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

I would point you toward a [great guide](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/dockerjava/) by microsoft, it's for java applications but you can get what you need out of it.

Solution in general:

1. Open the Azure Portal. Select + Create a resource and search for
   Container Registry. Select Create. In the Create Container Registry
   dialog, enter a name for the service, select the resource group,
   location and click Review + Create. Once the validation is success
   click Create.
2. In your CI build you need to have 2 tasks, 1 for the build/compose where you provide and another to publish the image to your Azure Container Registry. You will use the "same task" for this.
3. This container registry is where you store the outputs of your builds, similar to artifacts in traditional CI builds. This is where you publish your application from during a release to on-prem or cloud.

You can read more about the parameters you need to provide and the settings in details [in the guide](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/aspnetmodernize/).

P.S. Here is an [example on how to](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/aspnetmodernize/) dockerize and existing .NETCore application.